# Composer и Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer, install

Пробую установить Laravel, поставил соотвественно Composer на CentOS6, зашел в директорию домена (куда переместил файлы после распаковки Laravel) пробую установить "# composer install", начинает ругаться следующим 
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed
что не так делаю и как подправить?

Comment: не запускайте composer от root'а

Comment: У меня приложение убивалось после `Updating dependencies` на слабом VDS (если точнее, то не хватало оперативки). Попробуйте арендовать более мощный сервер в плане оперативки. Если, конечно, вы делаете всё на VDS.

Comment: от рута просит мануал, кто я такой что бы сопротивляться)
решено увеличением характеристик хоста.